# JavaFX Scene: Add Scene To Tab

Tags: java, javafx, scene

```
Tab tab1 = new Tab();  
Tab tab2 = new Tab();
```

How do I add a scene to a Tab? 
I want to make it so when tab1 is selected the scene is showing and when switched to tab2, it is not there.

I tried doing `tab1.setContent`, it has to be a node.
I tried doing `dialog.setOwner(tab1)`, it has to be a window.

```
    TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
    Tab tab1 = new Tab("FIRST TAB");
    Tab tab2 = new Tab("SECOND TAB");
    tab1.setContent(new VBox(new Text("Scene Below:")));
    tab2.setContent(new VBox(new Button("dsadsadassda")));
    tabPane.getTabs().addAll(tab1, tab2);

    final Stage dialog = new Stage();
    dialog.initModality(Modality.NONE);
    dialog.initOwner(tab1); // I can't, it has to be a window
    dialog.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
    dialog.show();

    stage.setScene(new Scene(tabPane, 1000, 680));
    stage.setMaximized(true);
    stage.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

well the design depends on what you want to do , in your case you should specify a CustomTab that extends the JavaFx Tab and as default it would hold a ScrollablePane or whatever pane you want , which will be bound to have the same width and height as the Tab, so when you do setContent() you should be able to pass every JavaFx's object, because you will add that object to the inner tab pane.